# How does one trace recursive calls using the Java Debug Interface?

Tags: java, debugging, recursion, interface

How does one utilize the **Java Debug Interface** to trace the recursive calls that presumably will be made in evaluating the expression `Main.reverseString ( args[0] )` in file `Main.java`?

Here is the file `Main.java` :

```
public class Main
  {
  public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
    System.out.println ( "args[0] ..... " + args[0] ) ;
    String reversed = Main.reverseString ( args[0] ) ;
    System.out.println ( "reversed .... " + reversed ) ;
    } // main
  public static String reverseString ( String s )
    {
    if ( s.length() <= 1 )
      return s ;
    return ( (new StringBuilder(reverseString(s.substring(1))))
                              .append(s.charAt(0)).toString() ) ;
    } // reverseString
  } // Main
```

My tracing program (`RecursionTracer`) is shown below :

```
import com.sun.jdi.* ;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.* ;
import com.sun.jdi.request.* ;
import com.sun.jdi.event.* ;
import java.util.* ;

public class RecursionTracer
  {
  public static void main ( String [] args ) throws Exception
    {
    LaunchingConnector launchingConnector
      =  Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().defaultConnector() ;
    Map<String, Connector.Argument> env
      =  launchingConnector.defaultArguments() ;
    env.get("main").setValue ( Main.class.getName() ) ;
    VirtualMachine vm = launchingConnector.launch(env) ;

    ClassPrepareRequest classPrepareRequest
      =  vm.eventRequestManager().createClassPrepareRequest() ;
    classPrepareRequest.addClassFilter ( Main.class.getName() ) ;
    classPrepareRequest.enable() ;

    EventSet eventSet = null ;
    do
      {
      eventSet = vm.eventQueue().remove() ;
      for ( Event event : eventSet )
        {
        if ( event instanceof ClassPrepareEvent )
          {
          MethodEntryRequest methodEntryRequest
            =  vm.eventRequestManager().createMethodEntryRequest() ;
          methodEntryRequest.addClassFilter ( Main.class.getName() ) ;
          methodEntryRequest.enable() ;
          } // if ClassPrepareEvent

        if ( event instanceof MethodEntryEvent )
          {
          System.out.println ( "\n--------------------------------------" ) ;
          MethodEntryEvent methodEntryEvent = (MethodEntryEvent) event ;
          com.sun.jdi.Method method = methodEntryEvent.method () ;
          System.out.println ( "MethodEntryEvent has occurred ..." ) ;
          System.out.println ( methodEntryEvent ) ;
          System.out.println ( method ) ;
          System.out.println ( "======================================\n" ) ;
          } // if MethodEntryEvent

        vm.resume() ;
        } // for each event
      }
    while ( eventSet != null ) ;
    } // main
  } // RecursionTracer
```

I compile both `Main.java` and `RecursionTracer.java` as follows :

```
del *.class
D:\Java\JDK-11~1.1\bin\javac.exe -g Main.java RecursionTracer.java -Xlint:unchecked
```

When I run the `RecursionTracer`, its output is :

```
D:\>D:\Java\JDK-11~1.1\bin\java.exe RecursionTracer

--------------------------------------
MethodEntryEvent has occurred ...
MethodEntryEvent@Main:5 in thread main
Main.main(java.lang.String[])
======================================

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl.removeUnfiltered(EventQueueImpl.java:200)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl.remove(EventQueueImpl.java:97)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl.remove(EventQueueImpl.java:83)
    at RecursionTracer.main(RecursionTracer.java:26)
```

I had expected to see `MethodEntryEvent`s occur each time method `Main.reverseString` is entered, but, as one can see from the above output, the only `MethodEntryEvent` is when execution enters `Main.main`.  Why are there not also `MethodEntryEvent`s displayed for `Main.reverseString`?  Moreover, how can I get such `MethodEntryEvent`s to be displayed? Finally, it would be nice to see the argument that is supplied to `Main.reverseString` with each invocation of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see any other methods because your code doesn't make any method calls - instead, it gets an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the very first line of the main method, since you're not passing any arguments to your `main` method.

A simple solution is to modify your `main` method, and add this as the very first line:

```
args = new String[]{ "foobar"};
```

this will give it something to reverse. There should be a way to pass arguments when you're launching the JRE using the `LaunchingConnector`.